# How to make a filter in javascript which filters div by checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need make a filter by checkboxes, which will specify two or more options in one category. My filter filters one option in each category.

```js
function change() {
  let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result > div'));
  // Hide all results
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    result.style.display = 'none';
  });
  // Filter results to only those that meet ALL requirements:
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filter input[rel]:checked'), function(input) {
    const attrib = input.getAttribute('rel');
    results = results.filter(function(result) {
      return result.classList.contains(attrib);
    });
  });
  // Show those filtered results:
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    result.style.display = 'block';
  });
}
change();
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <h1>Select models</h1>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="apple" onchange="change()"/>Apple</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="samsung" onchange="change()"/>Samsung</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="xiaomi" onchange="change()"/>Xiaomi</label>
  </div>
  <h1>Select processors</h1>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="a9" onchange="change()"/>A9</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="a8" onchange="change()"/>A8</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="snapdragon" onchange="change()"/>Snapdragon</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="exynos" onchange="change()"/>Exynos</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <div class="apple a9">
    <h1>iPhone 7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="apple a8">
    <h1>iPhone 6</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="samsung exynos">
    <h1>Samsung s7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="xiaomi snapdragon">
    <h1>Xiaomi Redmi note 4x</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in result I cannot choose Apple and Samsung simultaneously. I can choose only one options in each group. It is like a radiobutton. But I need checkbox with multiply options

Comment: Do you want to combine those filters (e.g: apple AND snapdragon) or just multiply them? (e.g: apple OR snapdragon)

Comment: @zeropublix I need to make a opportunity to choose more options in each group. For example, If I choose Samsung and Apple, as a result, nothing is shown, but need to be shown apple and samsung simultaneously. Could I explain my issue?

Comment: @Mr.Chingis what if you choose apple samsung and snapdragon?? Should the result be all the 4 phones or none(since samsung and apple does not have snapdragon)?

Comment: @sanatsathyan none. Because choosen products have no snapdragons processor. If I choose apple samsung xiaomi and snapdragon, result should be only one phone xiaomi. Because from choosen phones, at least one phone has snapdragon, so result should be xiaomi

Comment: @Mr.Chingis did any of the Answers solve your question? then mark them as that please or a little "thanks" is appreciated as we took the effort to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand you (by reading the comments) You want to have the the following behaviour:

- The model or processor checkboxes are "OR" correlation inside their filter-group.
- **But** the phone has to be of any checked model **and** must have any of the checked processors.

This code should solve your issue/question:

```js
function change() {
  var modelCbs = document.querySelectorAll(".models input[type='checkbox']");
  var processorCbs = document.querySelectorAll(".processors input[type='checkbox']");
  var filters = {
    models: getClassOfCheckedCheckboxes(modelCbs),
    processors: getClassOfCheckedCheckboxes(processorCbs)
  };

  filterResults(filters);
}

function getClassOfCheckedCheckboxes(checkboxes) {
  var classes = [];

  if (checkboxes && checkboxes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      var cb = checkboxes[i];

      if (cb.checked) {
        classes.push(cb.getAttribute("rel"));
      }
    }
  }

  return classes;
}

function filterResults(filters) {
  var rElems = document.querySelectorAll(".result div");
  var hiddenElems = [];

  if (!rElems || rElems.length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < rElems.length; i++) {
    var el = rElems[i];

    if (filters.models.length > 0) {
      var isHidden = true;

      for (var j = 0; j < filters.models.length; j++) {
        var filter = filters.models[j];

        if (el.classList.contains(filter)) {
          isHidden = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (isHidden) {
        hiddenElems.push(el);
      }
    }

    if (filters.processors.length > 0) {
      var isHidden = true;

      for (var j = 0; j < filters.processors.length; j++) {
        var filter = filters.processors[j];

        if (el.classList.contains(filter)) {
          isHidden = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (isHidden) {
        hiddenElems.push(el);
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < rElems.length; i++) {
    rElems[i].style.display = "block";
  }

  if (hiddenElems.length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < hiddenElems.length; i++) {
    hiddenElems[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="filter">
    <h1>Select models</h1>
    <div class="models">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="apple" onchange="change();"/>Apple</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="samsung" onchange="change();"/>Samsung</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="xiaomi" onchange="change();"/>Xiaomi</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Select processors</h1>
    <div class="processors">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="a9" onchange="change();"/>A9</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="a8" onchange="change();"/>A8</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="snapdragon" onchange="change();"/>Snapdragon</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="exynos" onchange="change();"/>Exynos</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    <div class="apple a9">
      <h1>iPhone 7</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="apple a8">
      <h1>iPhone 6</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="samsung exynos">
      <h1>Samsung s7</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="xiaomi snapdragon">
      <h1>Xiaomi Redmi note 4x</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Code is working, when div products have no div on the inside. For example,
`<div class="apple a9"><div class="head"><h1>HEAD</h1></div></div>` In this case code is not giving result

Comment: @Mr.Chingis of course it doesnt work then, because the selector i used is `var rElems = document.querySelectorAll(".result div");`
to make it work like that you should either give every first level div a specific attribute or maybe using `var rElems = document.querySelectorAll(".result > div");` might work ( did not test it ).

Answer (score 1):

try this,or you can see the demo ahead:https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/gzs3fr7n/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="height=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://livejs.com/live.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="test2.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    function change() {
        let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result > div')),
            modelsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.models:checked'),
            processorsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.processors:checked');
        // Hide all results
        results.forEach(function(result) {
            result.style.display = 'none';
        });
        // Filter results to only those that meet ALL requirements:        

        filterModelsOrProcessors(modelsChecked);

        if (processorsChecked.length != 0) {
            filterModelsOrProcessors(processorsChecked);
        }

        function filterModelsOrProcessors(modelsOrProcessorsChecked) {
            results = Array.from(modelsOrProcessorsChecked).reduce(function(sum, input) {
                const attrib = input.getAttribute('rel');
                return sum.concat(results.filter(function(result) {
                    return result.classList.contains(attrib);
                }));
            }, []);
        }
        // Show those filtered results:
        results.forEach(function(result) {
            result.style.display = 'block';
        });
    }
    change();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="filter">
        <h1>Select models</h1>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="apple" class="models" onchange="change()" />Apple</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="samsung" class="models" onchange="change()" />Samsung</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="xiaomi" class="models" onchange="change()" />Xiaomi</label>
        </div>
        <h1>Select processors</h1>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="a9" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A9</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="a8" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A8</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="snapdragon" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Snapdragon</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="exynos" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Exynos</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <div class="apple a9">
            <h1>iPhone 7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="apple a8">
            <h1>iPhone 6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="samsung exynos">
            <h1>Samsung s7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="xiaomi snapdragon">
            <h1>Xiaomi Redmi note 4x</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```